# Should the jar file contain dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

We're going to run a project with the java -jar ABC.jar command.
Now we have the situation that ABC.jar depends on many other jars, such as log4j, spring,mybatis, etc......
With maven, we can package in two ways.
One is to package all dependent jars and ABC.jar  into one jar，the other is ABC.jar and dependent jar are packaged separately, and then they are packaged into a tar.gz and uploaded to the production server.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Keep them separate. That way they can be updated independently.

Comment: The term you're looking for is a "fat jar", and the best approach will depend very much on how your deployment process works. Most modern deployments that create a frozen stateless image and run it work very well with fat jars.